# Inner Join and Outer Join In Odata

Tags: rest, join, odata, inner-join, outer-join

I ma trying to consume data from an OData Service.
I want to know Is there any concept of inner and outer join in OData?If not, is there any way to carry out the same.

CustomerID----------------------CustomerName
1 -----------------------------------Alfreds Futterkiste
2------------------------------------Ana Trujillo
3   ---------------------------------- Antonio Moreno

And a selection from the "Orders" table:

OrderID--------CustomerID

10308------------------2

10309-----------------37

10310----------------77

Output should be in case of Outer Join---

Name-------------------------------OrderId

Alfreds Futterkiste-----------------null

Ana Trujillo------------------------10308

Antonio Moreno----------------------null

null--------------------------------10309

null--------------------------------10310

What will be OData URL for this case?

Comment: Can you give a simplified example of your source data and expected outcome? And does it need to be one url call or do you have tools to make one call and then iterate over the first resultset to produce a second?

Comment: @mdisibio I have edited the question.Please check

Answer (score 1):

For OData V4.0, there is an [extension for data aggregation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html), in which the [Cross-join concept](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html#_Toc378326314) is presented.

Comment: This is not there in OData v2 .Right?

Comment: You can achieve the similar result of inner join and outer join using $expand and $filter for related entity sets.

Comment: GET ~/Table1?$expand=NavigationProp_TAble2  This query by default returns Outer Join?

Comment: @user3580062 This is Inner Join, I think.

Comment: @Maya,According to my understanding,it is left Join i.e. Table1 Left Join Table2

Comment: @YiDing Can youplease give an example for the same.What will be filter and expand values in case of Oute and Inner join

Comment: @user3580062 Inner join sample is "GET ~/Table1?$expand=NavigationProp_Table2 & $filter=NavigationProp_Table2/$count gt 0". The sample given by you presents left outer join.

Comment: @YiDing This does not work http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories?$expand=Products&$filter=Products/$count gt 0

Comment: Well, it should as appending /$count to navigation collection and filter the entity set according to its value is supported by the protocol: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_Toc372793692. But it seems that currently none of the services published on www.odata.org has implemented this feature.

Answer (score 1):

In Sql Server, you would need to issue a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to obtain the above results. However, the results you posted can only be obtained if there is no database enforced Foreign Key relationship on Order.CustomerId, otherwise, every Order would have a Customer, and the first column would never have nulls.

(A `CROSS JOIN` would simply match every Customer with every Order.)

So the `FULL JOIN` sql query would be:

```
         SELECT ISNULL(C.CustomerName,'') AS CustomerName, ISNULL(O.OrderId,0) AS OrderId
           FROM Customers C
FULL OUTER JOIN Orders O ON C.CustomerId = O.CustomerId
```

I am not aware of any oData syntax to produce such a result from an entity model based on both tables. However, if it was truly needed, you could produce a view using the above syntax, and then create a single oData entity representing the results of a full join, and query for it.

Assuming you create such a view, and use some default values instead of nulls as above, the oData syntax would simply be:

`/CustomerOrders()?$expand=Customer,Order&$select=Customer/CustomerName,Order/OrderId`

which produces:

```
CustomerName                       OrderId
Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados 10308
                                   10309
                                   10310
Alfreds Futterkiste                    0
Antonio Moreno Taquería                0
```

My C# `CustomerOrder` class/model looks like this:

```
public class CustomerOrder
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public int OrderId { get; set; }

  public int CustomerId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
  public Customer Customer { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
  public Order Order { get; set; }

}
```